# Cannot Import MousePosition from folium.plugins

Tags: folium

I can't Import MousePosition from folium.plugins. I am having the below error when I execute these codes. How should I go about it?
Thank you. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install specific version of folium i.e. 0.7

Below command:

> pip install folium==0.7.0

And then restart Kernel

Hopefully this will be resolve your issue!

Answer (score 0):

It's horrible, I've been straggling with it myself for weeks.

It only works on Python3 Jupyter notebooks run on the web. Try loading the lab notebook on https://jupyter.org/ in your browser (I use chrome).
Once the kernel dies and restarts however, it will failed to load again. You'll have to close the tab and re-launch the binder all over again.

It won't load on Anaconda kernels either.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Google Colab, it worked for me there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).